# How to change time-scheduler on runtime

Tags: spring, scheduler

I am using schedulers from spring framework. I want to configure the Scheduler time via jmx-console on run-time. Is this possible?

e.g. @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * *") i want to give new values on run time

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's at all easy right now, but certainly possible.  You have to expose a mechanism to re-inject the trigger bean into the scheduler.  I did it here if you want to see one option: https://github.com/SpringSource/cloudfoundry-samples/blob/master/stocks/src/main/resources/server-bootstrap-config.xml.